# Python files - Write to new line each time opened

Tags: python, file, tkinter

What i'm trying to do is each time the function AppViewer_SAVE is called via a tkinter button, for it to open the file and write the data. My problem is each time the function is called and writes, it doesn't write to a new line, it just overwrites the data that is on the first line, heres the code:

```
def Appviewer_SAVE(self):
    target = open("saved", "w+")
    target.write("%s\t" % App_InfoTrans0())
    target.write("%s\t" % App_InfoTrans1())
    target.write("%s\n" % App_InfoTransfer_Gender) #\n doesn't make a difference here
    target.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
def Appviewer_SAVE(self):
    target = open("saved", "a")
    target.write("%s\t" % App_InfoTrans0())
    target.write("%s\t" % App_InfoTrans1())
    target.write("%s\n" % App_InfoTransfer_Gender) #\n doesn't make a difference here
    target.close()
```

**'w+' Mode:**

> Opens a file for both writing and reading. Overwrites the existing
>   file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new
>   file for reading and writing.

**'a' Mode:**

> Opens a file for appending. The file pointer is at the end of the
>   file if the file exists. That is, the file is in the append mode. If
>   the file does not exist, it creates a new file for writing.

You can over view all the mode of files at this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I never even knew files had append.. guess I should go learn more about files

Comment: Trying to accept the answer, asks me to wait a few minutes first. I'll accept it asap

Answer (score 1):

You want to either open the file in append mode with

```
open(filename, 'a')
```

Though append mode sometimes has some platform-specific differences in behavior, so another option is to open in write mode and manually seek to the end

```
f = open(filename, 'w') 
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
```

In the future, check the Python docs for [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). It states there explicitly 
"(note that'w+' truncates the file)". If you're working with Python 3 make sure to refer explicitly to the docs for the Python version you are using, as some of the modes and arguments accepted by open() are different.